# Drupal 7: redirecting non-/ urls to / for google pr purpose. "trailing slash" at the end of urls

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, url, redirect, drupal-7

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site. it is a redesign from Codeigniter and the client wants to keep same urls for not to loose his Google PageRank. so I defined custom urls for pages at page-edit pages. The problem is, client wants the urls with "trailing slash" at the end of urls.

how can I redirect all non-/ urls to / for Drupal 7?

for example the url is http://www.example.com/aboutus

and I need it to be http://www.example.com/aboutus/

*I can't add this slash in custom path input at page editig form since Drupal says "do not use trailing slash"*

and I have many urls like this, and most of them dynamically generated urls. so maybe some .htaccess trick?

Thanks a lot! appreciate helps!!!

---

**UPDATE 1** for useful info about "using trailing slashs" http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slashforward/

---

**UPDATE 2**

I tired the code below, but not working :/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://www.example.com/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

I have some particular urls that I need to redirect until I sort out this redirecting all urls issue. So I wrote the code below to htaccess

```
redirect 301 "/aboutus"  http://www.example.com/aboutus/
```

and it redirects to http://www.example.com/aboutus/////////////////////
and it boviously doesn't work. What am I missing!?

---

++++++++++++ **SORTED** ++++++++++++

place the code to the top of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How does Drupal's rewrite rule(s) look? If **it** can't handle the trailing slash, of course you're going to get 404'd. Also, you should somehow tell it to generate links with a trailing slash, rather than keeping the old links and doing a redirect. That just gives you an extra http query every time someone clicks a link = slower response time.

Comment: SORTED, please see the update in question above.

Comment: Did you intend your "SORTED" section to mean that's your solution?  If so, you should probably add it as an answer.  However, while it looks like that will work for your _incoming_ links, I don't think it addresses what nitro said about links that drupal itself _generates_ to other parts of the site, such as in the menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

++++++++++++ SORTED ++++++++++++

place the code to the top of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```